# Tar compress folder without specifying the filename

Tags: bash, command-line, tar

Is it possible to use tar to compress a folder without giving the filename of the archive to store in?

Normally you use:

```
tar -zcvf prog-1-jan-2005.tar.gz /home/jerry/prog
```

I want to do something like

```
tar -zcvf /home/jerry/prog
```

and have it create prog.tar.gz

Comment: Unless playing with a wrapper around tar, you cannot do that. `tar` has usage and options: this is not your average `winzip`.

Comment: this would be very useful to be able to tar every folder within a folder. I haven't found a good work around for zipping but I use this to unzip them all: `find . -exec tar xvfz {} \;` It would be nice if there was a similar easy way to zip all at once.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `tar` this way. Or you need to patch it.

If you don't give a file (you don't use the `-f` option), `tar` will use the standard output by default, i.e. the terminal and eventually fail because it will refuse to write compressed data on the terminal.

So, you have to call `tar` the proper way : `tar -zcvf prog.tag.gz /home/jerry/prog`.

Comment: For `tar` to use STDOUT, you must specify it: `tar -zcvf - /home/jerry/prog `: as the `-f` option has been set.

Comment: You're right! I meant without the `-f` option. If you give the `-f` option and no file, `tar` will just fail.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know, it is not possible, mainly because the "destination name" argument comes first. If you ommit it, then the "source" argument is placed instead of the destination one and it confuses tar.

If your needs are for a script where you do not know the archive name to create, you could consider parsing your path and create a name to provide to the tar command.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Laurent's suggestion I wrote this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function isIn()
{
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    return
fi

for i in "${EXPECTED_ARGS[@]}"; do
    if [ "$i" == "$1" ];then
        return 1
    fi
done

return 0
}
EXPECTED_ARGS=( 1 )
E_BADARGS=65

if isIn $# ; then
  echo "Usage: $0 filepath"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi

FILEPATH=${1%/}
filename="${FILEPATH##*/}"

tar -zcvf "$filename.tar.gz" "$FILEPATH"
```

I'm new to this so if you see anything wrong please contribute.